# Condense a multi-row, multi-column formula output into a single row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a `QUERY` formula that imports the first three rows of some data,  `"Select Col1, Col2 Order by Col2 desc limit 3"`, producing an output like this:

```
   |   c1   | c2
r1 | Red    | 53
r2 | Blue   | 45
r3 | Yellow | 15
```

I'd like to get need those same formula values to look like this:

```
   |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |   c5   |  c6 
r1 | Red  |  53  | Blue |  45  | Yellow |  15
```

where the whole output is in a single row.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, wrap your query function with [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, QUERY(....))
```

To get multiple columns, you would wrap this with [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625), and instead of joining on `" "`, join with some arbitrary delimiter that is guaranteed to not be in the query result. If you expect a wide variety of text to be a possible formula result, you may need to get quite creative, or use unicode.

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-;-", TRUE, QUERY(....)), "-;-", FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I added =SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",,Query Formula),"-")

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell from the original post format that you wanted separate columns. That's a good way to get it back to multiple columns!

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(QUERY()&""),""))
```

- Concatenate the query result with a Weary cat
- Split the cat

Comment: Is `arrayformula` even needed? `Split` will fill out as needed