# How to create single list from two ranges in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheet I have 2 ranges of variable length with some data,i.e.

- column A: aa, ab, ac;  and
- column B: ba, bb, bc.

I would like to combine them in one long list in column C with a some formula:

- column C: aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc.

I thought that UNIQUE function could work if it took 2 ranges- but it does not or ARRAYFORMULA but does not look like this is a sensible idea.

So looking for solution or direction.

Thank you!

Marek

Comment: @I'-'I I think it's sufficiently different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309180/condense-a-multi-row-multi-column-formula-output-into-a-single-row , as there a distinct relationship exists between each column. Here, it appears there is no such relationship - i.e. both ranges contain the same category of content.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here is my solution:

To combine two ranges into a single column, join them with curly braces with a semi-colon in-between. Example:

```
={(A3:A7);(B3:B7)}
```

In my specific situation I used the following:

```
=UNIQUE({(A3:A7); (B3:B7)})
```

Which successfully outputs only the unique values from the joined range.

Thanks!